# How to properly do a template of a templated class?

Tags: c#, .net, templates

I have the following definitions for a class (I'm working with graphs, trying to work with them in a Generic Way).

```
public class SparseGraph<NodeType, EdgeType> : IGraphType<NodeType, EdgeType>
where NodeType : INode
where EdgeType : IEdge
{
...
}

public class ConcreteNode : INode
{
...
}

public class ConcreteEdge : IEdge
{
...
}

public class PathFinder<GraphType, NodeType, EdgeType> where GraphType<NodeType, EdgeType> : IGraphType<NodeType, EdgeType>
where NodeType : INode
where EdgeType : IEdge
{
...

...
}
```

Every time I have to instantiate the PathFinder class i.e. for a SparseGraph, I have to do it by using the following declaration:

```
var a = new PathFinder<SparseGraph<ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>, ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>()
```

The PathFinder class has a template of a template. Personally I dislike this kind of "redundancy" on this type instantiation. Is there any way to reduce the signature of the class PathFinder to something like "public class PathFinder"?

Comment: As a side note, according to the [C# naming convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic2), your generic type parameters should be called `TNode` and `TEdge` instead of `NodeType` and `EdgeType`.

Comment: If your goal is just to minimize the amount of code you have to read and type, you can also consider the "using" directive to create an alias: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would implement more specific sub types for each of the common cases you are using, for example in the case of a "SparseGraph"

```
public class SparseGraphPathFinder : PathFinder<SparseGraph<ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>, ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder: what about being able to declarate the class with just "public class PathFinder<TGraph>" so I could use any type of graph for the pathfinder? How can I compress the <GraphType, NodeType, EdgeType> declaration?

Comment: You could create a "ConcretePathFinder", something along the lines of public class ConcretePathFinder<TGraph> : PathFinder<TGraph, ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge> but I think you are on the borders of getting into messy inheritance trees here. Have you considered refactoring to use composition instead?

Answer (score 2):

Inherit from

```
PathFinder<SparseGraph<ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>, ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>
```

ie.

```
public class NewClass : PathFinder<SparseGraph<ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>, ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>
```